# Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to minimize regular expressions without Kleene closures/stars?

Tags: regular-expressions, complexity-classes, finite-sets

I have read that minimizing regular expressions is, in general, PSPACE-complete. Is it known whether minimizing regular expressions without the Kleene closure (star, asterisk) is in P?

The language of any such regular expression would be guaranteed to be finite. I suppose an equivalent question is whether the problem of constructing a minimal regular expression from a known finite language is any easier than minimizing an arbitrary regular expression. It seems like this should be the case.

Comment: The question was discussed some time ago on our sister site cstheory: [minimizing size of regular expression for finite sets](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16917/12122). Hermann Gruber notes there that the complexity of the problem is in the lower levels of the [polynomial hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy).