# Minimal regular expression from minimal NFA for finite language in polynomial time?

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions, nondeterminism, finite-sets

Given a minimal NFA for a finite language, is there a polynomial-time algorithm to find a minimal regular expression for the same language?

This question is based on a recent question regarding minimization of regular expressions for finite languages given a regular expression. I was surprised to learn there don't appear to be any stronger results. (see [Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to minimize regular expressions without Kleene closures/stars?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/114950/69))